# How to perform a many-to-many match (in same table) in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains employee information.  This table shows the entire employee hierarchy.  A given employee may be at any level of the hierarchy.  If I want to know a given attribute of a specific employee, I can write my SQL statement using the where clause

```
where 'myEmployee@mycompany.com' in ANY(manager_3, manager_4, manager_5, manager_6, employee_email)
```

This works fine.  The challenge is when I have multiple employees (which may or may not be managers).  I cannot change the table structure. My query end result is to list all the individual people that are in the hierarchy chain of 1 or more employees. Assume I have 3 people.  I don't know what level of the hierarchy they are at. I need to find everyone who reports up to these 3 people in the hierarchy. What I need to do is something similar to this (and I know this is NOT valid SQL)...

```
select employee_email from myTable
where ('Emp1@company.com', 'Emp2@company.com', 'Emp3@company.com') = 
     Any(manager_3, manager_4, manager_5, manager_6, employee_email)
```

Is there a cleaner/more optimal way to write this that using 3 separate ANY clauses?

**** EDIT *****
Just for people searching on this later, I ended up using the  SUB_QUERY listed in the answer, but instead of doing multiple queries from DUAL, I used a split routine...

```
WITH
    Q_STR AS (SELECT 'YOUR,COMMA,SEPARATED,STRING' STR FROM DUAL)
SELECT
    TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE) COL1
FROM Q_STR, 
XMLTABLE(('"' || REPLACE(STR, ',', '","') || '"'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```sql
SELECT employee_email
FROM   myTable
WHERE  manager_3 IN ('Emp1@company.com', 'Emp2@company.com', 'Emp3@company.com')
OR     manager_4 IN ('Emp1@company.com', 'Emp2@company.com', 'Emp3@company.com')
OR     manager_5 IN ('Emp1@company.com', 'Emp2@company.com', 'Emp3@company.com')
OR     manager_6 IN ('Emp1@company.com', 'Emp2@company.com', 'Emp3@company.com')
OR     employee_email IN ('Emp1@company.com', 'Emp2@company.com', 'Emp3@company.com')
```

or:

```sql
SELECT employee_email
FROM   myTable
WHERE  'Emp1@company.com' IN (manager_3, manager_4, manager_5, manager_6, employee_email)
OR     'Emp2@company.com' IN (manager_3, manager_4, manager_5, manager_6, employee_email)
OR     'Emp3@company.com' IN (manager_3, manager_4, manager_5, manager_6, employee_email)
```

or join to a sub-query factoring clause containing the desired values:

```
WITH lookup_emails (email) AS (
  SELECT 'Emp1@company.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emp2@company.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emp3@company.com' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.employee_email
FROM   myTable t
       INNER JOIN lookup_emails l
       ON l.email IN (t.manager_3, t.manager_4, t.manager_5, t.manager_6)
```

or combine the two previous using `EXISTS` (rather than `IN`):

```sql
WITH lookup_emails (email) AS (
  SELECT 'Emp1@company.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emp2@company.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emp3@company.com' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT employee_email
FROM   myTable t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   lookup_emails l
         WHERE  l.email IN (t.manager_3, t.manager_4, t.manager_5, t.manager_6)
       )
```